# Finding Derivative using Limit Laws

Tags: limits, derivatives

Find the derivative of $\frac{x}{(1+2x)}$ using limit laws.

I get stuck with the algebra once I set it up to

$$\frac{\frac{x+h}{1+2x+2h} - \frac{x}{1+2x}}{h}$$

Comment: Did you  try to put the two terms in the numerator over a common denominator? If so, what did you get?

Comment: You're saying $\frac{x+h}{1+2x+2h} - \frac{x}{1+2x} = \frac{x+h-2hx}{1+2x+2h}$? If so, this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{(1+2x)} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x+h}{1+2x+2h}-\frac{x}{1+2x}}{h} &\text{apply limit definition}\\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{(x+h)(1+2x)}{(1+2x+2h)(1+2x)}-\frac{x(1+2x+2h)}{(1+2x)(1+2x+2h)}}{h} &\text{find common denominator}\\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{(x+2x^2+h+2xh)-(x+2x^2+2xh)}{(1+2x)(1+2x+2h)}}{h} &\text{combine into one fraction} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{h}{(1+2x)(1+2x+2h)}}{h}& \text{collect like terms at top} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \frac{h}{(1+2x)(1+2x+2h)} &\text{multiply the reciprocal} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{(1+2x)(1+2x+2h)} & \text{cancel the $h$'s} \\
&=\frac{1}{(1+2x)(1+2x)} &\text{plug in $h=0$}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1+2x)^2} &\text{simplify the final answer}
\end{align}

Comment: But then I can't plugin h as 0.

Comment: Hm...why did you plugin x as 0 in the 4th step on the top--if that is what you did? And thank you for writing that out.

Comment: @user1419623 Although there is still an $h$ in the expression that glace gave you above, suppose you tried to use the limit definition of derivatives to find the derivative of $f(x) = x$, there won't be an $h$ in the remaining expression...

Comment: @user1419623 I didn't plug $x=0$. The terms on the top just canceled each other out, so we are left with $h$. (Note that the negative was distributed to the second parentheses group.)

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Ah, while I was typing in my (originally) more detailed steps, I see you've improved your answer quite a bit! +1 for the explanation of the steps, something I didn't think of.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}
\;\; = \;\; \frac{\frac{(x+h)}{1 \; + \; 2(x+h)} \; - \; \frac{x}{1 \; + \; 2x}}{h}
\;\; = \;\; \frac{\frac{x \; + \; h}{1 \; + \; 2x \; + \; 2h} \; - \; \frac{x}{1 \; + \; 2x}}{h}
 $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{h} \cdot \left[ \frac{x \; + \; h}{1 \; + \; 2x \; + \; 2h} \;\; - \;\; \frac{x}{1 \; + \; 2x} \right]    $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{h} \cdot \left[ \frac{x \; + \; h}{1 \; + \; 2x \; + \; 2h} \cdot \frac{1 \; + \; 2x}{1 \; + \; 2x} \;\;\;\; - \;\;\;\; \frac{x}{1 \; + \; 2x} \cdot \frac{1 \; + \; 2x \; + \; 2h}{1 \; + \; 2x \; + \; 2h} \right]    $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{h} \cdot \left[ \frac{(x + h)(1 + 2x)}{(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} \;\;\;\; - \;\;\;\; \frac{x(1 + 2x + 2h)}{(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} \right]    $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{h} \cdot \left[ \frac{(x + h)(1 + 2x) \;\; - \;\; x(1 + 2x + 2h)}{(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} \right]    $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{(x + h)(1 + 2x) \;\; - \;\; x(1 + 2x + 2h)}{h(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{(x + h + 2x^2 + 2hx) \;\; - \;\; (x + 2x^2 + 2hx)}{h(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{x + h + 2x^2 + 2hx - x - 2x^2 - 2hx}{h(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{h}{h(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{(1 + 2x + 2h)(1 + 2x)} \;\; \longrightarrow \;\; \frac{1}{(1 + 2x + 0)(1 + 2x)} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{(1 + 2x)^2}  $$